# Implementing long division using a generator function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, division

As an exercise to try to understand generator functions I am trying to write a function that simulates long division and returns the number one digit at a time. I have written this function and it doesn't seem to work. However if I step through it line by line in the shell it does exactly what I want it to do so I'm not sure what to do going forward. I've read through posts on the internet about generator functions here:

and from what I understand I just replace the return statement with a yield statement. Is this not the case? Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

```
def decimals(number):    
    """
    Takes a numnber and generates the digits of  1/n.

    """
    divisor = number
    dividend = 1


    while dividend % divisor != 0:
        #Floor division is the // operator        
        quotient = divisor // dividend
        remainder = dividend % divisor

        temp = quotient * divisor
        if remainder != 0 :
            temp = quotient * divisor

        if temp > dividend:
            dividend = dividend * 10
            dividend = dividend - temp
        else:
            dividend = dividend - temp
        yield quotient



def main():
    gen = decimals(4)
    print(next(gen))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with it. You haven't really described the problem. Second. If the number divides into infinity, the program will never stop. The print function will lag because of the amount of data it's trying to output.

Comment: Minor comment, you can reduce your quotient/remainder calculation to `quotient, remainder = divmod(dividend, divisor)`.  Actually...why do you have the two reversed in what you have; isn't `divisor` over the `dividend` backwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is that you output only a single value from the generator: `next(gen)`. To output the whole generator, make a list from it's values: `print(list(decimals(4)))`, or print it value by value:

```
for digit in decimals(4):
    print(digit)
```

To deal with endless generators (e.g., from a `decimals(3)` call), you can for example take only a limited amount of values from it with `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import islice
for digit in islice(decimals(3), 10):
    print(digit)
```

Also, I think there is something wrong with your algorithm. It doesn't seem to produce the correct results. I think, it should look something like this:

```
def decimals(number):    
    """
    Takes a number and generates the digits of  1/n.

    """
    divisor = number
    dividend = 1
    remainder = 1

    while remainder:
        #Floor division is the // operator        
        quotient = dividend // divisor
        remainder = dividend % divisor

        if remainder < divisor:
            dividend = remainder * 10
        else:
            dividend = remainder
        yield quotient
```

As a side note, this code may still be made shorter. For example:

```
def decimals(number):    
    dividend = 1
    while dividend:      
        yield dividend // number
        dividend = dividend % number * 10
```