# implementing a NONinfinite generator

Tags: generator, python-3.6

I am borrowing some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424349/implementing-long-division-using-a-generator-function-in-python) but I have no idea how to get the code to not run infinitely.

Specifically, what I don't know how to do is to reference previously yielded digits and check that if the currently yielded digit has been returned. I want the function to stop once it starts looping. Is there a way to reference previously yielded values?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non generator solution

```
#when doing long division on a pair of numbers, (a,b), when you proceed through the algorigthm, 
#you get new pairs (rem,b). You stop the algorithm when rem==0 or when the remainder is present
#in the existing list of digits
def decimals(number):
    dividend = 1
    digit = []
    while dividend:
        if dividend//10 in digit: 
            return digit
        digit += [dividend // number]
        dividend = dividend % number * 10
```

a more streamlined version, again still not generator, would be

```
def decimals(number):
    dividend = 1
    digit = []
    while dividend and dividend//10 not in digit:
        digit += [dividend // number]
        dividend = dividend % number * 10
    return digit
```

Comment: I suppose you can simply add a yield statement to the while loop to constantly yield each new digit: yield digit[-1] then simply